# Eloquent - Select one column with the same name from two different model

Tags: php, eloquent, slim

I have `Student Model` and `User Model` which has one column with same name (`token`). The case is when I post `token` either from users page or students page, I want to process that request with single controller. What I've tried,

```
Class DataController
{
    public function deleteData($request, $response)
    {
        $token = $request->getParam('token');

        $user = User::where('token', $token)->first();
        $student = Student::where('token', $token)->first();

        if ($user) {
            $user->delete();
            // flash message user's data deleted
            // redirect to home
        }

        if ($student) {
            $student->delete();
            // flash message student's data deleted
            // redirect to home
        }

        // flash message error
        // redirect to home
    }
}
```

Is there a way to select one column from two models? Is my code wrong based on SOLID principles? How can I clean up my code? I'm still learning about refactoring method for flexibility and have no idea how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the conditionals, just two queries.

```
User::where(compact('token'))->delete();
Student::where(compact('token'))->delete();
```

Why you want to do this, I'm unsure. If a `Student` is related to a `User` you should maintain that relationship with a foreign key.

Unrelated tips:

- Consider using `$request->input('token')` instead of `getParam()`. The latter only looks at the querystring and unless there is a reason for it, sticking with `input()` is a safe way to pull request data from either the querystring or request body.
- Make sure you validate `$token` before applying it to the database query. Check at the very least that it's not empty before performing the deletion.
- Learn about authorization. Realizing this may be a simplified representation of your controller, as it stands anyone can delete any user by passing a valid token.

Comment: There is no relationship between `Student` and `User`. Can you tell me what compact does in that query? What if (for some reason) the token does not supplied or does not match for both models (just precaution), its an error isn't it?

Comment: If token doesn't match any record, nothing gets deleted. You don't get an error if you run `delete from users where token = 'non-existent-token'` against your database. Laravel won't complain either.

Comment: `compact('token')` is equivalent to `[ 'token' => $token ]`. I find it simpler to read, especially when the where conditions build up, ie. `compact('token', 'username', 'email')` vs. `[ 'token' => $token, 'username' => $username, 'email' => $email]`

Comment: If there is no relationship between the two models, you should consider having two separate controllers. A `UserController` and `StudentController`, each with their own `destroy()` method that deletes from their respective model.

Comment: I have `UserController` and `StudentController` separately. `DataController` just for delete or register data for `User` and `Student`.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is, if there is no relationship between the two models, a single action should probably not be used to handle the deletion of them. The functionality specific to each model should be placed in the controller corresponding to each.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that. One more thing, I got an error from $request->input('token'): `Call to undefined method Slim\Http\Request::input()`

Comment: My bad, use `getParam`. I didn't realize you were using slim!

Comment: from [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php): So `compact('var1', 'var2')` is the same as saying `array('var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $var2)` **as long as `$var1` and `$var2` are set**.